# How to skip self signed check in the SSL_set_verify()

Tags: c++, c, security, ssl, openssl

I'm writing a small program with the OpenSSL library that is suppose to establish a connection with server and make a check that the server certificate match with a local certificate. This server dispenses a self-signed certificate, which causes the handshake to fail with self signed certificate error message.

I am using the function:

```
SSL_set_verify(tls->ssl, SSL_VERIFY_PEER, NULL);
```

Comment: You should not skip the check for self-signed certificates since otherwise an attacker could simply provide a self-signed certificate within a man-in-the-middle attack. Instead you should check that exactly the specific self-signed certificate is expected. This can for example be done by adding it to the trust store.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Man in the middle can not attack since there is another check of the peer certificate that should match a local certificate saved in my device.
So I want to skip the sefsigned check and keep only the check o the peer cert with my local cert

Comment: Aren't you then basically asking how to completely disable certificate validation (and only do your own check later)? This is done by using `SSL_VERIFY_NONE` instead of `SSL_VERIFY_PEER`.

Comment: as I know the `SSL_VERIFY_NONE` is used in the check of the peer cert with a local cert. Otherwise how to make it?

Comment: `SSL_VERIFY_NONE` disables checking the certificate during TLS handshake. From my understanding you somehow want to check the certificate outside the handshake and  this can be done even if `SSL_VERIFY_NONE` set.